# Uploading files using remote:true and remotipart + carrierwave gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jquery-fileupload-rails, remotipart

I want to make remote file upload via remotipart + carrierwave. The problem is that my upload works, but it seems that it is uploaded as usual html. Or it is uploaded via ajax, but appropriate js file is not called.
I have a form_for with remote:true, and a corrseponding controller method create. Since the form is submitted as js, create.js.erb is used.

```
<% if @syllabus.errors.present? %>
  $('#syllabus-errors').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/error_messages', object: @syllabus)   %>');

<% else %>
  alert("ds");
  $('#modal-body').html(<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/thanks')   %>);
  $('#syllabus-errors').html("");
<% end %>
```

Logs show this:

```
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered layouts/_error_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered syllabuses/create.js.erb (12.0ms)
```

It is kinda strange that error_messages are rendered earlier that create.js.erb,  error_messages are being rendered inside create.js.erb.

Comment: can post the controller code for the create action? Your js.erb looks fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding this if:

```html
<% if remotipart_submitted? %>

<% else %>

<% end %>
```

don't know why it didn't work without it.